# Server-to-server (Linux) VPN best practices?

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, ipsec

I manage several CentOS and Fedora VMs, and our setup is getting sufficiently sophisticated that it's time to move several resources on a single back-end VM, and serve those out to our Web VM, QA VM, Dev VM, etc. We trust our VM provider, but we don't trust every random stranger who can buy a VM on the same subnet for a few cents per hour. We need to encrypt traffic between the client servers and the back-end server. We have enough CPU headroom that symmetric encryption is no problem, but SSL handshake on each request would add too much latency, so application-level encryption is out of the question. We need some sort of VPN, but there are a lot of different ways to do it, and the numerous well-documented VPN configurations that are fine for attended client systems really don't make sense in this setup.

Which Linux VPN packages are best suited for this use case?

Which package-agnostic design principles should I keep in mind?

Comment: I must be missing something, why do you need to set up VPNs because of the other users on the same subnet?

Comment: Because other VMs on the same subnet could sniff traffic.

Comment: Sorry, I am still mystified, how would another host on the same subnet sniff your traffic without the collusion of your hosting company?

Comment: @chris: are you sure you're on the same broadcast domain?  i.e. can _you_ see any ARP traffic from other hosts you don't control?

Comment: @blankabout If (and only if) there are other clients on the same broadcast domain, the other clients could ARP poison to man-in-the-middle traffic between other hosts on a switched network.

Comment: @blankabout Xen guest network bridging depends on the host running in promiscuous mode, so the hosting provider has no way to distinguish a guest sniffing packets from normal operation.

Comment: Did you check out http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-network-config-ipsec-host.html which discusses how to use racoon to do the ipsec host-to-host configuration?

Comment: @Christopher Evans: I did. I'm a bit concerned that since the ipsec configuration doesn't give you a separate IP for the tunnel, it's difficult to tell, short of tcpdump, whether you're communicating over an encryped link or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your exact requirements, but OpenVPN (http://openvpn.net/) is easy to configure, available as a package in most distributions, works over either tcp or udp, has flexible routing options, and otherwise seems to meet your needs.  I use it regularly as an "unattended" solution (comes up when the server boots, does not require human intervention).

An added bonus is the cross-platform (OS X, Windows, Linux, *BSD), which makes it convenient if you need to extend your VPN to your laptop/desktop/etc platform of choice.